# How do I make an HTML file appear at my extension page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How do I specify an HTML document as the page to pop up in `chrome-extension://MYID`? Here's what it looks like right now:

[image: File Not Found]

You can see there is no file there. Is there a way I can specify an HTML file to appear here?

Comment: The question is currently unclear. Show your manifest.json and describe the goal of this page, how it'll be opened (by the user or on event).

Comment: @wOxxOm just how do I specify a page to appear at this URL?

Comment: Since the browser doesn't have a built-in server, there's nothing at this URL. You need to add a real file name that exists in the extension package/directory to the end of the URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm how do I do whatever that is?

Comment: You create that file in a text editor and then save it to the extension directory. Looks like we still don't understand each other because nothing you're asking seems related to extensions development.

Comment: @wOxxOm oh I understand now. I thought I would have to register pages to appear here, I didn't realize it was just a directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an HTML document to the topmost directory of the extension, let's call it `menu.html`. Then add `/menu.html` to the end of that URL. This will then pop the page up. The `extension://MYID` is just a directory of the extension.